# Dynamic javascript reference

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, vb.net, visual-studio-2003

I've inherited some code (not mine- I swear!) which uses a session variable in the header of the HTML to determine which javascript file to link to.

i.e.

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" src="../JavaScript/<%=Session("jsFileName")%>.js"></SCRIPT>
```

It does work, except that it won't let me change to design view. It gives the message

"*Could not open in design view. Quote Values differently inside a '<%... "value" ...%>' block.*"

Anyone got any suggestions as to a workaround, that doesn't involve a huge rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" src='../JavaScript/<%=Session("jsFileName")%>.js'></SCRIPT>
```

Notice use of `'` instead of `"` for *src* attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just comment out the SCRIPT tag in code view and then swith to design view?

Or replace the outer double quotes with single so you have:

```
src='../JavaScript/<%=Session("jsFileName")%>.js'
```